# Access is denied when trying to build a Docker image with selenium/standalone-chrome

Tags: python, docker, selenium

I'm trying to build a Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install selenium==4.1

# Copy src contents
COPY /src /app/


# Expose the port
EXPOSE 8501

# Execution
ENTRYPOINT [ "streamlit", "run" ]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

However, when I execute `docker build .`, I get the following error:

```
[+] Building 0.2s (6/10)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 369B                                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/selenium/standalone-chrome:latest                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/selenium/standalone-chrome:latest                                                                                                                                0.0s 
 => ERROR [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 61.51kB                                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => CACHED [2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
------
 > [internal] load build context:
------
error from sender: open src\dist\parser\botocore\data\chime-sdk-messaging: Access is denied.
```

I've read in the Internet that this can happen when Docker is not able to find the selenium image from the Docker Hub. However, I've checked, and that image is available on the Docker Hub. I've even been able to pull it using docker `docker pull selenium/standalone-chrome`. Anybody has encountered something similar or knows what is going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've been testing other images, like alpine or python:3.7, and I'm obtaining the same error. Did I skip any step to be able to use images from Dockerhub?